# How to solve without split

Tags: python

#### Directions:

Create a program in a file that reads words.txt in order to:

- Determine the length of the longest word(s) and output that length plus the first word of this length found.
- Determine the length of the shortest word(s) and output that length plus the first word of this length found
- Determine and output the average length of all the words in the list.
  You should strip white space from each word before using its length in your calculations.

#### Solution Output:

```
The longest words are 21 characters; an example is counterdemonstrations
The shortest words are 2 characters; an example is aa
The average word length is 7.933511409466738
```

This is the code I have so far. I am not allowed to have `split()` there but I don't know how to solve without it

```py
def main():
  min_char = 100000
  max_char = 0
  min_word = ""
  max_word = ""
  char = 0
  total = 0
  word = open("words.txt")
  for line in word:
    for word in line.strip().split():
      if len(word) < min_char:
        min_char = len(word)
        min_word = word
      if len(word) > max_char:
        max_char = len(word)
        max_word = word
      char = char + 1
      total = total + len(word)
  avg = str(total / char)
  
  print("The longest words are", max_char, "characters; an example is", max_word)
  print("The shortest words are", min_char, "characters; an example is", min_word)
  print("The average word length is ", avg)
```

[Code screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXvoF.png)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "we'll do your work for you for free" site.
Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?more_on=xron.net). People here regard that as evil.

Comment: Hi @shreypandiri--see [reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow) if you're unsure of how to place code in your question.  Placing code should avoid additional downvotes your question is getting.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to recode main fuction using your own split function which also removes whitespaces as follows.

**Code**

```
def mysplit(s):
  ''' My own split function 
      (replaces line.strip().split())
  '''
  istart = iend = 0
  words = []
  s = s.strip()            # remove white space around s
  for x in s:
    if x == ' ':
      if istart < iend:
        words.append(s[istart:iend])
      # advance pass space
      istart = iend + 1
      iend = istart
    else:
      iend += 1

  if istart < iend:
    words.append(s[istart:iend])

  return words

def main():
  min_char = 100000
  max_char = 0
  min_word = max_word = ""
  char = total = 0
  
  with open("words.txt") as word:
    for line in word:
      for word in mysplit(line):
        if len(word) < min_char:
          min_char = len(word)
          min_word = word

        if len(word) > max_char:
          max_char = len(word)
          max_word = word
          
        char = char + 1
        total = total + len(word)
  avg = str(total / char)
  
  print("The longest words are", max_char, "characters; an example is", max_word)
  print("The shortest words are", min_char, "characters; an example is", min_word)
  print("The average word length is ", avg)
  
main()
```

**Test**

File: words.txt

```
The following example shows how to 
use a default parameter value.

If we call the function without argument
it uses the default value
```

**Output**

```
The longest words are 9 characters; an example is following
The shortest words are 1 characters; an example is a
The average word length is  4.782608695652174
```